# How do I delete the messages from a user's DMS

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

I want to make a command where the bot can clear every message that it sent to the author's by DMs. How do I do this?

Comment: You can only delete your own messages in DMs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the message that is sent to the author and then delete it after condition x is fullfilled.

**Take a look at the following example:**

```py
import asyncio

@client.command()
async def testdm(ctx):
test = await ctx.author.send("This is a test")
await asyncio.sleep(5) # For example if you want to wait 5 seconds
await test.delete()
```

Based on the comment from Łukasz Kwieciński you, can also use:

```py
await ctx.author.send("This is a test", delete_after=5) # Seconds are customizable
```

*Note that the bot can't delete your messages.*

Comment: An easier way would be to simply add the delete_after kwarg in ctx.author.send